# Splitting html templates in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm looking some way to split complicated template to few ones. 
When create page with few tabs - template file structure come to be ugly and complex. This is bad way. I can split templates with creating new by

```
template(name="some")
```

and then

```
{{>some}}
```

But it's mean i need to make helpers, events_handlers, etc for each template. But much of data for this templates will duplicate, so it's again not good way.
Maybe exist some way to split html, but not create few Template objects?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to divide your templates up as you suggested but have each inherit its events and helpers from a single template using the [template-extension package](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/template-extension). That should give you a logical division of template code without repeating yourself.